# Call to a member function get_setting() on a non-object in

Tags: discussion

my theme name is buisness.
 add_action('wp_head','buisness_customize_css');

function buisness_footer_callout($wp_customize){

```
$wp_customize->add_section('buisness-footer-callout-section',array(
'title'=>'Footer-callout',
));
$wp_customize->add_setting('buisness-footer-callout-headline',array(
'default'=>'example headline'

));
$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp-customize,
'buisness-footer-callout-headline-control',array(
'label'=>'Headline',
'section'=>'buisness-footer-callout-section',
'settings'=>'buisness-footer-callout-headline'

)));
```

}
add_action('customize_register','buisness_footer_callout');
function Call to a member function get_setting() on a non-object error showing